# Send email on error in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, error-handling

I need to implement email notification on every exception occurred in RubyOnRails project. I can do it manually. But I think that there is already such thing implemented with Rails 3.2.2. It would save me a lot of work if there is ability to configure email receivers etc.

Does anyone knows which gem to install or API to use in order to achieve this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/95-exception-notification

Answer (score 1):

[Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/pages/home) is a commercial hosted app, but it's really awesome and affordable. If you just have one project to monitor, there's a [free plan](https://airbrake.io/account/new/Free) or you can upgrade to the [$7 plan](https://airbrake.io/account/new?dev=true) for more features. The amount of time you'll spend trying to build this functionality yourself is not worth it, and that time should be spent on developing your own product.